# Can I mock a ref property using jest/rtl on a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I currently have a functional component with a helper function

```
function Component() {
    imgRef = useRef(null)     

    function helperFunction(node, ref) { 
        if (!ref || !ref.current) return; 
        ...do something    
    }     

    return (
       <Component onAlign={(node) => {helperFunction(node, imgRef)}>
           <img ref={imgRef} />
       </Component>
    )
}
```

And I can't seem to cover the edge case

```
if (!ref || !ref.current) return;
```

I've tried mocking the useRef to return null but it hasn't worked. Is there a way I would be able to test this or mock the ref property of the  to null?

Comment: You seem to have missed adding all relevant code. Can you edit your post to include also the test code you are trying to use? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With RTL you can´t! As you can check on [faq](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/faq/):

> **Help! I can't access component methods or the component instance!
> This is intentional.**
> We want you to focus on testing the output and functionality of the component as it is observed by the user and to avoid worrying about the implementation details of the component.
> We believe this leads to less brittle and more meaningful test code.

`Testing-library` also have some guiding principles that you can check [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/).

And complementing the answer, Is there any chance that `ref` will be null when `helperFunction` is called? Checking your code over i believe its not possible as you are explicit setting `<img ref={imgRef} />`. So maybe you just dont need this verification.

* Related to Jest, maybe you can force some mock on the Component. But again, you will be going against Guiding Principles from RTL.